# Nim setter procedure not being called

Tags: nim-lang

I'm trying to create a setter `proc` on my object

```js
type
  Animal = ref object of RootObj
    name: string
    age: int

proc `age=`(a: var Animal, value: int) {.inline.} =
  echo("setting age!")
  a.age = value

var a: Animal
new a
a.age = 10
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field simply has precedence. Typically you just name the field something else and implement a setter and a getter. But this would also be resolved by not exporting the field but exporting the setter from the module.

Comment: That works when accessing the setter from an external package. Is there a way for the setter to take precedence over the unexported field in the source package ? (using the same name)

Comment: No, there's no way to change the precedence rules